# Rails rendering div outside it's parent div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

I'm having an issue where an alert is being rendered outside it's container div.  I have a bootstrap flash helper and customer helper that is supposed to output an alert div.  But the alert div is being output after the `boostrap-flash` div.

```
# application.html.erb
# ..snip..
<div class="bootstrap-flash">
  <%= unconfigured_subscription_manager_alert %>
  <%= bootstrap_flash %>
</div>
# ..snip..
```

Looks good right?  Here's the output:

```
<div class="bootstrap-flash">

</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
  ..alert text..  
</div>
```

WTF?  OK here's the helper method:

```
def unconfigured_subscription_manager_alert
  return unless distributor_staff_signed_in? and 
    current_distributor.subscription_manager_options_set?

  raw("<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">..alert text..</div>")
end
```

The strangest thing is that the alert div is output whether I use any of the following syntax:

```
<% unconfigured_subscription_manager_alert %>
<%= unconfigured_subscription_manager_alert %>
<% concat unconfigured_subscription_manager_alert %>
```

None of which puts the div where it's supposed to go.  Another weird thing is that `distributor_staff_signed_in?` is false and the alert is still being shown.... so weird...

I tried restarting the server and swapping the positions of the helper method calls inside the `bootstrap-flash` div to no avail.  I also tried making an `unconfigured_subscription_manager?` helper and checking and doing it like this:

```
# application.html.erb
# ..snip..
<div class="bootstrap-flash">
  <% if unconfigured_subscription_manager? %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">..alert text..</div>
  <% end %>
  <%= bootstrap_flash %>
</div>
# ..snip..
```

To no avail.

Anyone got any ideas?  Thanks.

**UPDATE**

- tried putting binding.pry just above the `bootstrap-flash` div, `distributor_staff_signed_in?` was false and `unconfigured_subscription_manager_alert` returned nil, as expected
- cleared my browser cache, dropped the database and remigrated, problem persists :(
- posting full `application.html.erb` as requested in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9262655) (sorry, SO editor hates it)

**UPDATE 2**

**Somehow fixed it, no idea how... just my buggy code I guess... sorry for being [that guy](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png) lol.  Thanks to everyone who helped me!**

Comment: Checkout the `pry-rails` gem. It can help you debug your code. Once installed, put `binding.pry` in any location that you want to debug. Once your code hits that spot, your console will throw you into a debug session, and you can checkout what is going on with your code.

Comment: Can you share the entire `application.html.erb` in the question.

Comment: Is Rails rearranging the HTML or is it the browser? If it is the browser then you almost certainly have broken HTML somewhere: invalid nesting, missing closing tags, ...

Comment: @muistooshort checked the source with curl to be sure and it looks like it is rails rearranging it.  No broken tags...

Comment: @JustinWood thanks for that, what an awesome tool!  Didn't help me this time though, `unconfigured_subscription_manager_alert` returned nil and `distributor_staff_signed_in?` returned false... as expected.  I think I will try dropping the database and remigrating, some really weird shit going on here.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I posted the full `application.html.erb` in a gist (sorry the editor failed to render it).  Apologies for leaving out the other if block inside the bootstrap flash, but the problem exists with or without that block there. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9262655

Comment: @hamster What is the content of `subscriptions/subscription_expiring_alert`. Can you share?

Comment: @hamster Can you come on chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48530/ror ?